# Need a central proxy to dispatch web requests asynchrously but how do I add tasks to its event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm looking to implement a Proxy class, which is used by the rest of the application to send web request asynchronously, I need this class so that I can have a central point to control the traffic , e.g. to throttle the speed of sending the web requests.

Here's my take so far.. When `Proxy`class is initialized it creates a background thread which runs an event loop, I'm doing this because running an event loop in the main thread blocks everything that comes after it.

`get_async` is used to wrap synchronous method(`from_remote_server`) in an asyncio coroutine, `loop.run_in_executor` is used here, and by using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` I can effectively throttle the rate of firing web requests.

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class Proxy():

    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.p = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.start_event_loop, args=(self.loop,))
        t.start()

    def start_event_loop(self, loop):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        print('running loop')
        loop.run_forever()

    def from_remote_server(self):
        return 'hello'

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def get_async(self):
        print('calling server...')
        result = yield from self.loop.run_in_executor(self.p, self.from_remote_server)
        print('result returned')
        return result


proxy = Proxy()

for i in range(3):
    asyncio.async(proxy.get_async())

for i in range(3):
    asyncio.async(proxy.get_async())
```

When the client needs to send a web request, it then uses `asyncio.async(proxy.get_async())` to schedule the request in the event loop, this returns a `task` which can later be used to retrieve the result.

This code actually works...and the results are like:

```
running loop
calling server...
calling server...
calling server...
calling server...
calling server...
calling server...
result returned
result returned
result returned
result returned
result returned
result returned
```

Then I noticed a problem, if I put a line`sleep(5)` between the two for loops in the end:

```
for i in range(3):
    asyncio.async(proxy.get_async())

sleep(5)

for i in range(3):
    asyncio.async(proxy.get_async())
```

Then the output only shows 3 `calling server...` as if the second loop didn't add new tasks to the event loop.

```
running loop
calling server...
calling server...
calling server...
result returned
result returned
result returned
```

It's almost like I'll have to call `asyncio.async(proxy.get_async())` immediately for it to work..

I checked the status of the loop and thread and they look fine..

```
print(proxy.loop)
<_WindowsSelectorEventLoop running=True closed=False debug=False>
print(proxy.t)
<Thread(Thread-6, started 42484)>
```

This leads me to think this approach is probably just wrong and not the right way to use `asyncio`

Can someone shed some light on this? I'm not too familiar with asyncio in Python

Thanks.

PS: I can only use Python 3.4.3

Comment: I have updated my answer with `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling from a different thread, instead of `asyncio.async()` use:

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(proxy.get_async(), proxy.loop)
```

(I agree your approach is probably wrong - there seems to be too much combination of threads and asyncio here - but some information is missing to suggest the best solution for your needs. The main missing piece is who is calling `get_async()` and how it should get its result back.)